# Weird Apache requests

Tags: web-crawlers

I've recently migrated a client from a WIX site to a Wordpress site (running on an Apache server)

I am seeing quite a few requests in the apache log file in the format

```
site.name:443 2.2.2.2 - - [19/Mar/2024:12:01:26 +1300] "-" 408 3366 "-" "-"
```

(Where site.name and 2.2.2.2 are the sites name and an IP address).

The normal format of requests would be

```
site.name:443  2.2.2.2 - - date "GET /xxxxx" 200 BYTES? REFERER AGENT_STRING
```

I am not overly concerned as I expect it is dodgy bot activity, but does anyone know what bot/thing is likely originating these hits/what its looking for - and is it a bad idea to block IP addresses which have a "-" as a URL or agent?

Comment: Maybe they are probing your site for security holes, pinging it to see if it's up, or downright scraping content. I manage several large sites, and I generally block bad user agents, including empty ones. However, I would try first to assess where is it coming from, by checking the IPs involved - it can give you a hint if they are worth blocking or not.